YamlDotNet - how to handle versioning after object update?
I'm using YamlDotNet in my projects for quite a while, though I could use your help with the following issue I'm facing as one of the projects is evolving.
Imagine I'm serialising the following objects for some time already (I'll keep everything as simple as possible):
[YamlSerializable]
public class Trip
{
    [YamlMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [YamlMember]
    public int[] BreakTimestamps { get; set; }
}

The BreakTimestamps are timestamps, in seconds, from the beginning of the trip.
Now, assume I've collected quite a number of serialised objects (in files) for the trips I made in past years.
My project evolves and I'd like to collect more information concerning the trips, so I update my Trip class to the following:
[YamlSerializable]
public class Trip
{
    [Flags]
    public enum BreakType
    {
        Undefined = 0,
        Nutrition = 1 << 0,
        Sanitary = 1 << 1,
        Mechanical = 1 << 2,
        Sightseeing = 1 << 3,
        Other = 1 << (sizeof(int) - 1)
    }

    [YamlSerializable]
    public class Break
    {
        [YamlMember]
        public int Timestamp { get; set; }

        [YamlMember]
        public int Duration { get; set; }

        [YamlMember]
        public BreakType Reason { get; set; }
    }

    [YamlMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [YamlMember]
    public Break[] Breaks { get; set; }
}

The issue I'm facing is that if I use the new class for deserialisation of existing files, I won't get any information about the timestamps.
What I would like to achieve, is that if I deserialise the previous version, for each element in BreakTimestamps I'll create a new Break object and fill only the Timestamp property, thus I'll gradually update all the previous version objects.
Do you have any ideas on how to approach this issue?
I see the following possibilities:

keep the BreakTimestamps property also in the updated version for backwards compatibility, but that would create redundant information in each newly serialised object
add a property defining version number of the class, name the updated class as Trip_V2.0,  use deserialiser that ignores unmatched properties (var deserializer = (Deserializer)new DeserializerBuilder().IgnoreUnmatchedProperties().Build();), check for version and deserialise with respective target (<Trip> or <Trip_V2.0>)

I'd appreciate any other ideas.
For the most elegant solution let's assume that it's not the last update to this object class, I'd like to have the possibility for future updates.
Thanks for any suggestions.

For clarification - the data is distributed and quite often offline, hence not accessible for me for a one-time update. I'd rather update each object only after it's been accessed with the newer version.
